# Accessing NSarray values from another class

Tags: ios, arrays

I've been trying for days to access an alphabet array from another class, yet I can't figure it out! I know there are several posts similar to this one, but none of them were any help. Here is the interface and implementation portions of the Alphabet class containing the array.

```
    @interface Alphabet : NSObject {
    NSArray *abet;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *abet;
@end

    @implementation Alphabet
    @synthesize abet;

    - (id) init {
        if ((self = [super init])) {
        abet = [[NSArray alloc]  
    initWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",@"e",@"f",@"g",@"h",@"i",@"j",@"k",@"l",@"m",@"n",@"o",@"p",@"q",        @"r",@"s",@"t",@"u",@"v",@"w",@"x",@"y",@"z", nil];
        }
        return self;
    }

    @end
```

Here is the code in the class that I want to access the array

```
    @interface NewView () {

    Alphabet* ab;
}

    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    ab = [[Alphabet alloc] init];
}

    - (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [[Alphabet.abet] objectAtIndex:p];
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[[Alphabet.abet] objectAtIndex:p];
```

makes no sense.

It should be

```
[ab.abet objectAtIndex:p];
```

or just

```
ab.abet[p];
```

(whatever `p` is...)

Comment: Thank you, I could have sworn I tried that, but I obviously didn't